# Nginx configured with upstream sends FIN

Tags: java, sockets, tomcat, tcp, nginx

I have Nginx fronting a Tomcat 6.0 server, using an APR connector.

I have Nginx configured to communicate with Tomcat over HTTP/1.1:

```
http {
    ...
    upstream tomcat {
        server 127.0.0.1:8080;
        keepalive 16;
    }

    server {
        ....
        location ... {
            proxy_pass http://tomcat;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Connection "Keep-Alive";
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Tomcat is set to with a connectionTimeout of 60s and a keepAliveTimeout of 60s, and maxKeepAliveRequests set to "-1" (no limit).

I've been tracking sockets in TIME_WAIT state between Nginx and Tomcat, and noticed that once there are 500-600 established connections under moderate-to-heavy load, there are an equivalent number of TIME_WAIT sockets.

I collected a dump with tcpdump and analysed it with Wireshark, and noticed that it is always Nginx that is initiating the TCP connection termination by sending a FIN to 127.0.0.1:8080. Specifically, this tends to happen if the web service running in Tomcat takes about 8-10 seconds to respond. Nginx gets the HTTP/1.1 200 OK response from Tomcat, then waits a couple of seconds and sends the FIN/ACK to Tomcat.

Is there a way to keep the connections open? Increasing the keepalive setting to a large number (eg. 256) eliminates the TIME_WAIT sockets, but I would rather keep this value low and have Nginx keep the connection open.

I could very well be misunderstanding how this is working, and the behaviour I am seeing is actually desirable, in which case I would appreciate some enlightenment.